# solidity Contract Deployment Mistake Token Issue

Tags: solidity

There is a contract which generated lets say 1000 tokens , Owner got 100 tokens to himself .. Rest 900 Tokens are created but not in owners purse. Initial contract has no mining function etc .. so is it possible for to people access the tokens ? Can they be moved or are they locked for ever ...?

there is no trade / mining function built into original contract. Is their any ways to access them ?

Comment: You may need to provide the contract code/address for further details.

Comment: I just need to know is it possible to do something ...or shall i recommend a new contract deployment ?

Comment: You can create whatever you want in programming. Whether it's possible or not it's not the question

Comment: Yes , I agree But this specific contract is already deployed on chain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract only supports whatever functions are written in it. If it doesn't have some functionality, it can never be added to it. So if it has tokens but they can't be transferred, the tokens are next to useless.

Also, tokens aren't mined. Only Ethereum is mined.